# Why i get this error `Error (Data mining): Either the user, TEMP-USER\Administrator, does not have permission`?

Tags: sql-server, mdx, olap, cube

I Use SQL Server 2008 r2 And SSAS and i use AdventureWorks2008 data base.

I Write this Query In MDX Query in Sql server analyser.

```
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

I Get This Error

> Executing the query ...
>
> Error (Data mining): Either the user, TEMP-USER\Administrator, does not have permission to  access the referenced mining model, Adventure Works, or the object does not exist.
>
> Error (Data mining): Either the user, TEMP-USER\Administrator, does not have permission to access the referenced mining model, Adventure Works, or the object does not exist.
>
> Execution complete

Why i get this error ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you most use this query

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]  ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

it is necessary that defined COLUMNS in MDX query.

Answer (score 0):

With Member
test as  [Measures].[Sales Amount] - [Measures].[Discount Amount]
select   test ON COLUMNS
from [Adventure Works DW2014]